# How to create a custom event in jquery

Tags: jquery, keyboard-events, custom-events

I want to create a custom event that will be triggered whenever a numeric value is entered in an input `type="text"`. Alphabets should be ignored. `change` and `blur` events didn't work well for me.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried .keyup() or .keypress()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might still be able to use `change` or `blur` events, but insert some additional logic to detect if your input is something that you'd want to trigger an event with, so

```
$(".field").on("change blur keydown keyup", function(){
    if($(this).val().match(/^\d+$/){
      //your code
    } else {
      //do nothing
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily create custom events :

```
// handle event
$('#mydiv').on('customevent', function(e) { });

// trigger event
$('#mydiv').trigger('customevent');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a `keydown`, `keypress` or `keyup` event to catch input, and reject non-numeric input.

Out of these three options, for integer input, the `keypress` event very suitable.

```
$('input#selector').keypress(function(event) {
    if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) { // or:
  //if (!/\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

However, you should also use `blur` / `change`, to deal with input from copy-pasting/dragging.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( '#input-id' ).keyup(function(e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57 )
        {
            doThis();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you..

[Alphanumeric Demo](http://hdserv.me/jQuery/Samples/jQuery%20AlphaNumeric.html)

Answer (score 0):

good artical is here..http://javascript.mfields.org/2011/creating-custom-events-with-jquery/
but i cant think it needs .you can use keydown, keypress or keyup as suggested by Rob.